# how to adjust the top image to center when the browser is resized with multiple images stacked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been racking my brain on how to make the top most image adjust to the center like the text on this carousel.

http://nasfactor.com/themes/dotsquare/html/html/index.html

I have 3 images. One will be the base, the second is a pattern on top of that base and the third is a logo which I need to readjust whenever the size of the view changes (eg. mobile). Here's a fiddle of what I have at the moment

```
#header
        {
            position: relative;
            display: inline;
        }
.overlay-logo
        {

            background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/T3UwueF.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            z-index:2;

            position: absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            top:50%;
            left:40%;
        }
        .overlay-pattern
        {
            background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/XYwZohg.png');
            background-repeat: repeat;

            z-index:1;
            opacity:0.8;
            position: absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:400px;
            top:0;
            left:0;
        }
        #header-banner {
            color:#F0626A;
            background: url('http://i.imgur.com/u7yvl8I.jpg') no-repeat center center;
            height: 400px;

            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            padding: 150px 0 0 400px;

            /*position:relative;
            display: inline;
            background-size: cover;*/
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f4hd3pt6/

Lastly, whenever i readjust my browser a scrollbar at the bottom appears. I'm wondering if I did anything wrong on the section tag.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: it's hard to tell with your fiddle what is exactly happening since there are only two images, but using text-align: center; will keep everything in the div centered

Comment: You want to center the `.overlay-logo` class?

Comment: @Ferrrmolina , yes, the logo if you notice, when adjusting the size of that quadrant in fiddle the logo moves to the left and is not centered. I'm not sure what i'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this help you.

**HTML:**

```
<section class="header">
        <div id="header-banner">
            <div class="container overlay-pattern">
                <div class="overlay-logo"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
#header {
  position: relative;
}
.overlay-logo {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/T3UwueF.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height:100%;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  top:40%;
}
.overlay-pattern {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/XYwZohg.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0.8;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:400px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
#header-banner {
  color:#F0626A;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/u7yvl8I.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f4hd3pt6/1/)</kbd>

Comment: this worked perfectly! thank you! btw, was it because of the overflow?

Comment: Nice to hear that! :)